# Find line starting with specific word and then replace string between two words in that line

Tags: powershell

I have a Csv file which have huge data. I want a PowerShell script which will search for a line starting with number `19999`, if found then in that line replace whatever is between `IISST:` and `Progress` with word `Result`.

Below is example of data.

```
1 ABC Test data Test data IISST: I am OK with this Progress some more data
1299 Someone needs this Test data IISST: I am OK with this Progress some more data
19999 ABC Test data Test data IISST: I want to replace this text with Result word Progress some more data
20000 ABC Test data Test data IISST: I am OK with this Progress some more data
79837 Someone needs this Test data IISST: I am OK with this Progress some more data
```

I have wrote below code after 3 days of struggle. and this code is removing all lines from file and adding only one line which I updated.

```
$search= [regex] "^19999"
$FullContentofLine= Get-Content "O:\Temp\test.csv" | select-string $search
$linenumber=$FullContentofLine.LineNumber
$linenumber
$fullContentofFile=Get-Content "O:\Temp\test.csv"
$contentUpdate = $fullContentofFile[$linenumber-1] -replace [regex] "IISST:(.*?)Progress","IISST: Result Progress" 
#$contentUpdate
Set-Content "O:\Temp\test.csv" $contentUpdate
```

Answer (score 2):

For this task I would recommend you the use of a [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch?view=powershell-7.2) with the `-File` parameter to read your file and the `-Wildcard` parameter to match the lines ***starting with `19999` and containing `IISST:` and `Progress`***.

For replacement of the line, there is no need to create a [`Regex` instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=net-6.0), the [`-replace` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#replacement-with-regular-expressions) already understands *regular expressions*.

For the regex pattern being used, you can check https://regex101.com/r/adMCPg/1 for description.

```
$newContent = switch -Wildcard -File 'O:\Temp\test.csv' {
    # look for lines starting with `19999` and containing `IISST:` and `Progress`
    '19999*IISST:*Progress*' {
        # if a line was matched,
        # replace everything between `IISST:` and `Progress` with ` Result `
        $_ -replace '(?<=IISST:).+(?=Progress)', ' Result '
        # and go to next line
        continue
    }
    # if the line was NOT matched, output it as-is
    Default { $_ }
}
# replace the file with the new content
$newContent | Set-Content 'O:\Temp\test.csv'
```

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. now i am facing one issue if i use switch. issue is with encoding. i cannot control the encoding with switch its only possible with get-content.

Comment: @AdeelMushtaq it should detect the right encoding to read the file. If the issue is saving it with the same encoding, then `Set-Content` has a `-Encoding` parameter